# Why did Elric make it a condiditon that Imrryr be destroyed?

Tags: plot-device, elric-saga

In "The Dreaming City" first published in *Science Fantasy* number 47, June, 1961, and reprinted in *The Weird of the White Wolf* (1967) Elric VIII, exiled 428th Emperor of Melnibone, agreed to lead an attacking force from six of the young kingdoms thrugh the maze to attack the capital city, Imrryr, the Dreaming city.

In a meeting with the leaders of the attacking force a few days before the attack, Elric says:

> Imrryr fell, in spirit, five hundred yeas ago--she will completely fall soon--for ever!  I have little debt to settle.  This is my only reason for aiding you.  As you know I have made only a few conditions--that you raze the city to the ground and a certain man and woman are not harmed.  I refer to my cousin Yyrkoon and his sister Cymoril...

And his reason for requesting no harm be done to Yyrkoon and Cymoril are obvious.  Elric loves Cymoril and want the pleasure of dealing himself with Yyrkoon who usurped his throne and kidnapped his lover.

But why did Elric make a condition that Imrryr be destroyed?

In the Elric stories, Imrryr has been the capital of Melnibone the Dragon Isle for many thousands of years.  Melnibone ruled the whole world for ten thousand years.  And the Young Kingdoms have been independent of Melnibone for the last five hundred years but all their attacks on Melnibone have been defeated.  Imrryr has been the fabulusly wealthy world capital for ten thousand years and then a fabulously wealthy trading city for five hundred years.

And in ten thousand and five hundred years Imrryr has never been captured and looted by foreign enemies, and it has accumulated fabulous wealth.

The nearest equivalent to Imrryr in Earth history might be Constantinople, "this city of the world's desire".

After years of building, it was dedicated as the new capital city of the Roman Empire in AD 330.

And it was often beseiged by foreign armies seeking to capture and loot it, but they were always defeated for century after century, until Constantinople probably came to have the title of the impreial capital city which was which remained unlooted for the longest time.

Tarasis or Tarasikodissa was born in the mountains of Isauria in south eastern Asia Minor.  Emperor Leo I hired many rough Isaurian mountainers as soldiers, a possible balance to the many German soldiers in the Roman army.  Tarasis changed his name to Zeno about 465, and married Aridande, Leo I's oldest daughter, in 466.  Their son Leo was born in 467.  Leo I died in 474, an his grandson became emperor Leo II.  Zeno was soon crowned co-emperor, and became sole emperor when Leo II died in 474.

Zeo was overthrown and fled from Constantinople in 475.  Basilicus became the new Emperor.  Zeno built up an army and besieged Constantinople in 476.  Tdh senaze opened hte gates and allowed Zeno's troops in.  Even though Zeno might have been angry at the people of Constantinople for overthrowing him in the first place, his return to power seems to have been almost bloodless.

Emperor Justinian II reigned twice from 685 to 695, and from 705 to 711.  He was tyrannical and made himself very unpopular.  His nose was slit in 695 so he would be ineligible to regain the throne. After some adventures in exile, Justinian II received aid from Tervel, the Khan of Bulgaria.

> Tervel agreed to provide all the military assistance necessary for Justinian to regain his throne in exchange for financial considerations, the award of a Caesar's crown, and the hand of Justinian's daughter, Anastasia, in marriage.[22] In spring 705, with an army of 15,000 Bulgar and Slav horsemen, Justinian appeared before the walls of Constantinople.[22] For three days, Justinian tried to convince the citizens of Constantinople to open the gates, but to no avail.[26] Unable to take the city by force, he and some companions entered through an unused water conduit under the walls of the city, roused their supporters, and seized control of the city in a midnight coup d'état.[22] On 21 August,[3] Justinian regained the throne, breaking the tradition preventing the mutilated from Imperial rule. After tracking down his predecessors, he had his rivals Leontius and Tiberius brought before him in chains in the Hippodrome. There, before a jeering populace, Justinian, now wearing a golden nasal prosthesis,[27] placed his feet on the necks of Tiberius and Leontius in a symbolic gesture of subjugation before ordering their execution by beheading, followed by many of their partisans,[28] as well as deposing, blinding and exiling Patriarch Callinicus I to Rome.[29]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justinian_II#Exile

So Justinian II probably, killed, multilated, exiled, or imprisoned hundreds or thousands of enemies when he regained constantinople. But there is no evidence that he let the Bulgarian army into Constantinople or let the Bulgarians loot and plunder the city.

In 1195, Alexios Angelos, older brother of Emperor Isaac II Angelos, deposed his brother.  He blinded and imprisoned Isaac II.  Isaac's son Alexios Angelos (born c. 1182) was imprisoned.  IT probably wasn't too harsh, but Alexios was only 13 when he was imprisoned, and spent what might have otherwise been the best years of his life locked up. Alexios was about 18 when he was smuggled out of Constantinple in 1201 and went to the Court of his brother-in-law Philip, King of the Romans.

Alexios went to the Fourth Crusade at Zara in 1202 and offered the crusaders ships, military aid, and money to pay of their debts to Venice if they went to Constantinople to overthrow his uncle Alexios III.  The fleet arrived at Constantinople in 1202, and in July 1203 the crusaders assaulted Constantinople.  Alexios III fled, and the next day the citizens proclaimed Isaac II emperor again.  The crusaders had them make Alexios co emperor.

Alexios IV found himself unable to pay the crusaders all he had promished.  Relations between Alexios IV and the crusaders, between Alexios IV and the citizens of Constantinople, and between the crusaders and the citizens deteriorated.  Alexios Doukas Murzuphius revolted in January 1204 and killed Alexos IV about 18 February 1204, and was crowned Alexios V on 5 February 1204.  The Crusaders beseiged Constantinople again.  The crusaders captured Constantinople on 12-13 April 1204 and established the "Latin Empire of Constantinople.

> he Crusaders looted, pillaged, and vandalized Constantinople for three days, during which many ancient and medieval Roman and Greek works were either seized or destroyed. The famous bronze horses from the Hippodrome were sent back to adorn the façade of St Mark's Basilica in Venice, where they remain. As well as being seized, works of considerable artistic value were destroyed for their material value. One of the most precious works to suffer such a fate was a large bronze statue of Hercules, created by the legendary Lysippos, court sculptor of Alexander the Great. Like so many other considerable artworks made of bronze, the statue was melted down for its content by the Crusaders for surplus profit.[14]
>
> Despite their oaths and the threat of excommunication, the Crusaders systematically assaulted the city's holy sanctuaries, destroying or seizing all that was deemed remotely of value; little was spared, and the tombs of the emperors inside the Church of the Holy Apostles fell victim to such looting as well.[15] Of the civilian population of Constantinople, it is estimated 2,000 were killed.[3] The Crusaders, with poor leadership, also sacked churches, monasteries and convents.[3] The altars of these churches were smashed and torn to pieces for their gold and marble by the warriors.[15] Although the Venetians engaged in looting too, their actions were more restrained.[citation needed] Rather than destroying all around like their comrades, the Venetians stole religious relics and works of art, which they would later take to Venice to adorn their own churches.
>
> It was said that the total amount looted from Constantinople was about 900,000 silver marks.[16] The Venetians received 150,000 silver marks that was their due and the Crusaders received 50,000 silver marks. A further 100,000 silver marks were divided evenly between the Crusaders and Venetians. The remaining 500,000 silver marks were secretly kept back by many Crusader knights.[17][18]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sack_of_Constantinople#Sack_of_Constantinople

And of course Constntinple was not totally destroyed or devastated in this attack since the crusaders planned to make it the capital of their new empire.

And clearly Alexios IV had not made the Crusaders promise to destroy the city, no matter how angry he might have been at Alexios III and his supporters.

So why did Elric make the attackers of Imrryr agree to destroy the city?  Why was Elric so much more vindictive than the persons who were the most similar situation to him in real history?

Comment: I don't see how the over-long history lesson helps this question, which otherwise seems fairly straightforward.